# Solve a circuit with the nodal analysis (2)

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have the following circuit, and I have to find `Vo`:

[image: circuit]

I solved it in this way:

$$
i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = 0
\\
\frac{v_0 - 12}{4} + \frac{v_0}{6} + \frac{10 - 0}{2} = 0
\\
3v_0 - 36 + 2v_0 + 60 = 0
\\
v_0 = \frac{-24}{5} = -4.8 V
$$

But the solution is this:

$$
i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = 0
\\
\frac{v_0 - 12}{4} + \frac{v_0}{6} + \frac{v_0 - 10}{2} = 0
\\
3v_0 - 36 + 2v_0 + 6v_0 - 60 = 0
\\
v_0 = \frac{96}{11} = 8.727 V
$$

The only difference is the last term:

$$
My \space equation: \frac{10 - 0}{2}
\\
Solution: \frac{v_0 - 10}{2}
$$

But I don't understand: the 2Ω resistor is between the 10V voltage source and the ground, so the voltage across this resistor should be `10 - 0`. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap positions of 10V and \$\small 2\Omega\$ in the circuit diagram. It doesn't matter in which order the components are arrange in a series path.

Answer (score 0):

Well the 12v is greater than 10v obviously so The current will flow through Vo to gnd across 2 ohms which is i3 in this case . So 10V is decreasing the total potential difference , so the current flows through 10V (i3) should be Vo-10/2, because it is decreasing it should be negative in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your third current is wrong. You need to understand the difference between left-most branch and right-most branch.

On one the left most branch, we have a resistors between **potential node** Vo and **(+) potential node** of 12V. So current flowing through it is the difference of potential divided by the resistance $$ (V_o - 12) / R $$

However, on the right most branch. You have a resistor between the **(-) potential node** of voltage source, which means that this voltage source (10 volts) plus the voltage across the resistor (Whatever the current times the resistor) sum up to potential point Vo.

Below is a redrawn schematic, in case we neglect the rest of the circuits of what we're essentially seeing to find the third current.

[image: schematic]

$$ V_o = V2 + IR $$

Thus $$ (V_o - V2)/R = I_3  $$

To further clarify the ambiguity between left branch and right branch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI0Q8j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The voltage at the node \$V_o\$ can be seen as the positive terminal of a battery of \$V_o\$ volts facing the 2-ohm branch. If the branch were isolated, it would seem as though \$V_o\$ were in series with the 10 V voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS1XQ0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KVL, beginning from the negative terminal of \$V_o\$ and moving clockwise, we notice a potential rise of \$+V_o\$ as we move from \$V_o\$'s *negative* terminal to its *positive* terminal. Moving on, there's a potential drop of 10 V (written as \$-10\$) across the 10 V source, because we moved from its *positive* to its *negative* terminal. Thus, the voltage that appears across the 2-ohm resistor is \$V_o - 10\$ volts. And the current that flows through that branch can be obtained as \$(V_o - 10) / 2\$, according to ohm's law.